# WatIn multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, watin

How can I work with WatIn using `async` delegates? I tried, but it returned this error:

> The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to
>   ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you use `BeginInvoke()` on your delegates. They use the thread pool to do threaded work and the threads in the thread pool are all MTA's. You will have to do it the old fashion way by creating your own `Thread`. The thread class offers methods (`GetApartmentState` and `SetApartmentState`) to change the apartment model.

I guess you might need your own message pump as well in your `thread`.

Something like this might get you started:

```
var th = new Thread(() => { /* do work */ });
th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
th.Start();
```

Comment: If you are talking about the constructors of Thread I think you are wrong. If you are talking about something else, could you please clarify? I fail to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of how the IE COM interop works, it inherently needs to be run in a single-threaded apartment. The following is copied from the [watin.org] page on the subject[1](http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/)

> **Why is setting the ApartmentState needed in the first place?**
>
> Copied from MSDN:
>
> “Because COM classes use apartments,
>   the common language runtime needs to
>   create and initialize an apartment
>   when calling a COM object in a COM
>   interop situation. A managed thread
>   can create and enter a single-threaded
>   apartment (STA) that allows only one
>   thread, or a multithreaded apartment
>   (MTA) that contains one or more
>   threads.”.
>
> **Since Internet Explorer is not Thread safe we need to use STA.**
>
> Implications
>
> Using WatiN works fine in a console or
>   GUI application when you apply the
>   [STAThread] attribute to the main
>   method (the sole entry point of the
>   application). This way the main Thread
>   runs as STA and all goes well. When
>   using a runner like MBUnit, NUnit or
>   any other runner that starts the main
>   Thread, your code/tests depend upon
>   the ApartmentState the runner started
>   with.
>
> **Behaviour of WatiN when Thread is not an STA Thread.**
>
> WatiN will throw a
>   ThreadStateException when you create
>   an instance of the WatiN.Core.IE
>   class, to help you remind to set the
>   ApartmentState to STA.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RequiresSTA](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5) attribute, starting with NUnit 2.5.

*EDIT*

Use [Apartment](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes) attribute, starting with NUnit 3.0.